# Custom camel header not stored in JMS message property

Tags: apache-camel, camel-jms

I'm playing around with Camel, and as a simple testcase, I want to add an header to the incoming message and store it in a JMS queue (activemq). This is the code using the REST dsl:

```
rest("/query-set")
  .id("queryset-route")
  .get("{id}")
      .route()
          .process((exchange) -> {
              exchange.getIn().setHeader("myHeader", constant(UUID.randomUUID()));
          })
          .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
      .endParent()
      .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
      .to("jms:queue:querysetRequests?exchangePattern=InOnly");
```

Now when I do a GET with HTTPie (httpie.org):

```
http -a admin:admin GET http://localhost:8080/camel/query-set/someId?key=value 'Foo:bar'
```

and inspect the message in the queue, I notice the following:

- the {id} is extracted from the URL and present as JMS property
- the http query param (key=value) is available as JMS property
- the custom http header (Foo: bar) is present as JMS property
- the Basic auth header (admin:admin) is present as JMS property

**BUT**, my custom 'myHeader' with the random UUID as value is **NOT** present in as a JMS property.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `Processor` to set the header, and therefore you should just set the header value as-is. You should **not** use constant, eg

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("myHeader", UUID.randomUUID());
```

as its just plain regular Java code.

And mind that JMS spec forbids certain types in JMS properties (aka Camel headers). There is some details at: http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: And if this doesn't work try forcing the value to a string with `.toString()`